# How Do I Create a Sub-Directory in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

The application that I am trying to create will ave approximately 100 different fragments between 10 classes. In an effort to try and keep everything organized, I am trying to create a new directory under the res/layout to group the fragments of similar activities together. I right-click on the res/layout folder, and click "new" and select "Directory" After I mane the new directory whatever I wish I click ok. The folder fails to show up under the layout directory. I tried save-all, cleaning, and rebuilding the project to no prevail. I have also tried shutting the program down and restarting it, placing the directory manually into the application via explorer, and still nothing. It is also interesting that if I am to do it the regular way the folders are created within the exporter files, but I cannot see them. Any solutions? Thanks everyone

Comment: Also relevant https://github.com/eskimoapps/ResourceNestingExample

Comment: Thank you all! Great resource, now I just need to figure out how to use it.